# Executing HTML testsuite using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have recorded some simple selenium tests by Selenium IDE. Now I want to run those tests in Jenkins.
Which plugin to Jenkins do I need to do that? And how to run the tests step by step?
My test suite is in HTML.

Can you provide detailed steps for it?

Comment: Have you considered exporting you test suite to another language? Also, http://whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 0):

Why isn't enough to run the selenium tests from maven though jenkins? This is how we made it work. If your jenkins is running on unix environment you should bear in mind that additional configuration of the system are needed.